# Как создать соединение с vm на Google Cloud

Tags: python, клиент-сервер, google-cloud

Создал себе vm на Google Cloud и хотел попробовать пообщаться с машиной со своей локальной, но не получается совсем это реализовать.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind(("34.66.13.6", 5050))

sock.listen()

conn, addr = sock.accept()

print(conn)

data = conn.recv(1024)

print(data)
```

При запуске пишет "Can not assign requested address", хотя 34.66.13.6 указан как внешний IP для vm

Если поменять IP на внутренний, то соединения все равно нет.
Ну, и код клиента:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.connect(("10.128.0.2", 5050)) # -> IP менял в зависимости от IP принимающего сокета

sock.send("World, it's me".encode('utf-8'))

data = sock.recv(1024)

print(data)
```

С сетями очень плохо, рад буду любой помощи

Comment: а порт 5050 открыт? `sock.bind(('', 5050))` попробуйте

Comment: Создается сокет со всеми нулями в таком случае, до этого он тоже создавался, но с указанным IP. Для чего нужен IP forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код сервера который нужно запустить на `vm`

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', 5050))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

Код клиента который вы запускаете локально

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('34.66.13.6', 5050))
sock.send(b'hello, world!')

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

Далее если вы хотите использовать порт 5050 для подключения то нужно выполнить следующие шаги:

1. В `Google Cloud` откройте `VPC network` и перейдите в `Firewall`
2. По аналогии с `default-allow-http` настройте свое правило только с портом `5050`
3. Перейдите в редактирование своей `vm` и в пункте `Network tags` добавьте созданное вами правило с пункта 2
4. Перезагрузите на всякий случай `vm` (stop/start)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но возникли некоторые трудности и вопросы. По серверному коду, почему мы привязываемся к пустой строке и что нам это даёт?
По пункту два, у меня в списке правил не было default-allow-http, настраивал наугад, но указал, что tcp и порт 5050. Запустил на vm скрипт и после запуска клиентского скрипта код остановился с ошибкой "Удаленный узел принудительно разорвал соединение". Отчем говорит эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: О том что вы не можете подключиться в вашему серверу. Думаю что лучше перейти в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119969/room-with--) для дальнейшего обсуждения вашей проблемы